# Unable to execute function after get request - SoundCloud API

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

This is a weird problem and probably has an obvious solution. I'm simply trying to send an alert to the browser when the "new track" button is clicked. However after the button is pressed, the request is sent and a valid response is received, nothing happens. Regardless of what is put inside the get function, nothing seems to happen. If it's not obvious I'm pretty new to JS so if someone could shed some light on why this isn't working it'd be great!

edit: API_KEY is just a placeholder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>

    <script>
        SC.initialize({
            client_id: "API_KEY"
        });

        function newTrack(){
            SC.get("/tracks", {limit: 1}, function(tracks){
                alert("Latest track: " + tracks[0].title);
            });
        };
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="new track" onclick="newTrack()"/>
    <div id="track"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any error on browser console when you click the "new track" button ?

Comment: no errors, just the response from the request

Answer (score 0):

Part of the reason could be you are not getting any "tracks" from the SoundClound on the callback on the "get" call and you are trying to access the [0] index of null which is an error.. try this.

```
SC.get("/tracks", {limit: 1}, function(tracks){
            if(tracks && tracks.length > 0)
                alert("Latest track: " + tracks[0].title);
            else 
                alert('There are no tracks')
        });
```

Comment: Still isn't working. What's weird is that even if I just put "alert("hello world")", it still won't execute. It's like it's totally ignoring whatever I put as the callback function.

Comment: Well it works for me. try it in another tab, may be you have clicked "Prevent this page from create additional dialogues" which suppresses the alert method.

Comment: Really? What is your setup for running it?

Comment: It is Chrome, and urs ?

Comment: Chrome as well :/ So just to make sure, you tried this exact code and it successfully alerted you when you click the "get track" button? Because this is driving me crazy.